# pygame sound just pops-not the real song/sound

Tags: python, macos, controls, pygame, desktop

I have been working on a custom desktop for some time now (thanks to all who have helped along the way) and I:
am trying to write a "control" desktop for the user to mainly, as the name suggests, have fine control over their computer.
How does this relate to pygame?
one of the features of the control desktop is to play music. I have everything down except for the sound playing.
it always decides to make a "pop" instead of playing the actual song. Any help would be so greatly appreciated as I am kind of in a rush to get a "beta" out before summer is over.

Code:

```
class control():

    def ctr(self):
        print("Going to control Desktop for Jupee...")

        midnightbg = pygame.image.load("MidNightUI.jpg").convert_alpha()
        midnightbg = pygame.transform.scale(midnightbg, (winx, winy))
        screen.blit(midnightbg, (0, 0))

        pygame.display.update()

        songlist = []

        songlist = os.listdir("/Users/"+getpass.getuser()+"/Desktop/JupeeMusic")

        pygame.time.wait(500)

        a = 0
        songsinlist = 0

        for things in songlist:
            songsinlist = songsinlist + 1
        songlist.remove(".DS_Store")
        songsinlist = songsinlist - 1

        pygame.mixer.init()

        for items in songlist:
            print("Song found : "+items)

        while 1:

            mx, my = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
            if a > songsinlist-1:
                a = 0

            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                    print(mx, my, "is the location that the mouse button was pressed.")

                elif event.type == QUIT:
                    pygame.quit()
                    raise SystemExit
                elif event.type == KEYDOWN:
                    if event.key == K_LMETA:
                        print("Going to main desktop again...")
                        setup().setdesk()
                    elif event.key == K_RMETA:
                        print("Going to main desktop again...")
                        setup().setdesk()
                    elif event.key == ord("p"):
                        song = pygame.mixer.Sound(songlist[a])
                        song.play(0)
                        pygame.time.wait(600)
                        a = a + 1
                elif event.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                    if mx <= 50 and my <= 50:
                        song = pygame.mixer.Sound(songlist[a])
                        song.play(0)
                        pygame.time.wait(600)
                        a = a + 1
```

this is on a mac.

Answer (score 1):

If you are meaning to be using Python 3, check to make sure that you aren't running it with Python 2. Your `print`s are written like the Python 3 functions rather than the Python 2 statements, but they are still valid in Python 2. The parentheses are just treated as parentheses rather than function calls. I don't see any code in what you posted that would be invalid Python 2. It's definitely possible to write a project in Python 3 without doing anything that would upset the Python 2 interpreter, but would nonetheless give weird bugs, especially if you happen to have installed pretty much the same libraries for both versions of Python. (I've done it, but not with a big project.)

In Python 2, the `pygame.mixer.Sound` doesn't know whether a string object is a buffer or file name, so you are supposed to use the 'file' keyword to tell the it that you have passed in a file name. (Or alternatively, convert the file name to unicode.) In Python 3, the usage of unicode encoding everywhere prevents this ambiguity. (But `pygame.mixer.Sound` now treats bytes objects as being ambiguous.)

---

Edit: unrelated to your question, but just thought I'd point it out.

You have the following four lines in your code:

```
for things in songlist:
    songsinlist = songsinlist + 1
songlist.remove(".DS_Store")
songsinlist = songsinlist - 1
```

They should become:

```
songlist.remove(".DS_Store")
songsinlist = len(songlist)
```

Comment: Thanks, I am currently working on it, and thanks for pointing out those 4 lines of code that could be shortened. am I supposed to use __file__?

Comment: Thank you! It was the file keyword that I needed. Been fighting this for days

Answer (score 0):

I've taken a good look, and I can see what's wrong. In pygame, when using music, you should not load your files as meer sounds, but as music:

```
pygame.mixer.music.load(songlist[a])
```

This will make the music play in the background.